# Get return type from a map of generic functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following dictionary where functions are polymorphic, accept the same argument but return different result:

```js
const dict = {
  one: {
    foo<A>(a: A) {
      return [a] as const
    }
  },
  two: {
    foo<A>(a: A) {
      return [a, a] as const
    }
  },
  three: {
    foo<A>(a: A) {
      return [a, a, a] as const
    }
  }
}

type Map = typeof map
```

I'd like to get the function's return type from that dictionary, with the following helper:

```js
const wrapper = <N extends keyof Map, A>() => {
  const fn = (() => {}) as unknown as Map[N]['foo']
  return null as unknown as ReturnType<typeof fn<A>>
}
```

Trying to get the result *(For instance, what function named `two` will return if I'll pass `7` as the first argument)*:

```js
// returns: "readonly [7] | readonly [7, 7] | readonly [7, 7, 7]"
// expected: "readonly [7, 7]"
type Result = typeof wrapper<'two', 7>
```

The problem is that I get the result as a union containing return types from all functions instead of the result for the function `two`.

Seems like the generic `N` argument of a `wrapper` function is considered as a union even if I pass only one value as an argument.

How can I get the correct result? The complication is that I do not have access to the `dict` object since it's coming from the library.

[Code at TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgS2LAvDA3gWAFAxuAUwC4Mc88AzEEAHgEEA%20ACgEMS6BKU3cvAJwJQArnzAwA2iwC6MFhBihIUMuQC%20K1QBoVUAO4gSWHpWr1mbGJ269%20gkWMmbZMuQvDQVedTy06AFgLE1uRUtIys7FxGNjACwqISLE5JzrLyih7GMN5eON44UACeAA4EMAAiSKgwRaUgFPBVODgZsLp8LMWlfDBoNAByMAQAHlAEYHDyANYEhfUVVU7hXCgMwa0wFGJoTEwra%20iqXK5CYFNgILpirpXI4v1S4gDkoU9SKnH2MGBCADa-aRgp3Ol2u8gASnZRAAVEoEGi1AjzLZmBh5ZrYAD0mNiUMgJAARAIWHBwL9ChIAOwyAA%20uJJZIp4kpTmpMDpxNJYHJVNZrKkBJw2KGw1KyAIcEJnMZvJg1MF2ERMEhED%201Uh8TAsNKCLh83anW6NCeehAT1ZDAYQA) for the simplicity

Comment: [Instantiation expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) are a very new feature so I can't be 100% certain, but I think this is the same general problem as in [ms/TS#47240](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47240); inside the function, `fn<A>()` produces a union.

Comment: Since your question is "how can I get the correct result" then the above comment doesn't constitute an answer.  What do you mean that you do not have "access" to the `dict` object?  I'm not sure how to suggest anything if you can't rewrite `typeof dict`, but maybe I'm not understanding you.

Comment: You can't get the type checker to abstract things the way you want, but you can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGVyom) which gives you the same result and should warn you if your `DictMap` type diverges from `dict`.  Anyway, I'm happy to write all this up as an answer if you think it addresses your question.  If not, let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for your suggestions.

By not having access, I've meant that it's the code I can't change since it's coming from the library. But I certainly can import it and have access to its type.

Your suggestion looks good, but the `dict` object is dynamic and code generated. Meaning it changes over time, so it would be great if we won't need to hard code its properties in `DictMap`.

Can we probably have `DictMap` defined dynamically based on `dict` properties?

Comment: No you can't and that's what I meant when I said "you can't get the type checker to abstract things the way you want"; instantiation expressions cannot be abstracted over, you need to mention each property explicitly if you want the compiler to compute the return type for a given `A`.  You can play games like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgZJyW) but that's only if you know that the relevant return types are always tuples-containing-some-number-of-`A`-elements. You cannot both iterate over `dict`'s properties and do generic instantiation at the same time. Should I write up an answer?

Comment: I see, if you feel comfortable, feel free to write this up as an answer.

I've simplified the problem, the actual use case is pretty complicated.

I'm writing a library for Prisma to support polymorphic relations. So `dict` object is essentially a Prisma client which contains models(one, two, and three in the example) with methods like `findMany`, `findFirst`(foo in the example), and so on.

I want to get the result that is returned for a particular model from `findFirst` function. Since every model has unique set of fields, return  type of every function is wildly different.

Comment: @jcalz just to confirm, at the current moment there's no option to get the return type of a specific `foo` function from the `dict` if the output is unpredictable?

Comment: What do you mean by "specific `foo` function"?  [My first approach](https://tsplay.dev/WGVyom) certainly is grabbing the return type of specific `foo` functions.  Maybe you mean something different by "specific"?

Comment: ... I feel like I've said "no, this is not possible" multiple times now.  I'm not infallible so maybe I'm wrong, but as far as I am aware, it is currently impossible to do what you want in the abstract.  Arbitrary type manipulation of generic function types is not available to us.  We don't have https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213 and we don't have https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574 and we don't have https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466 and probably other things that would be needed to enable this in general.

Comment: @jcalz for instance "Get return type of `foo` function from property `two`" with constraints of not hard-coding `dict` object as `DictMap` and when output of `foo` function is unpredictable and differs from other `foo` functions completely.

Comment: You can change the output of `foo` and my approach would still work. Sorry, but I really don't understand '"Get return type of foo function from property `two`" with constraints of not hard-coding `dict` object as `DictMap`' and this communication barrier is becoming unpleasant. I will try one more time and then run away screaming: for each particular generic method of `dict` you can get its `ReturnType`, but *you cannot abstract over this*; you need to mention each one explicitly.  I have no insight into some other approach, and I believe it is beyond TS's abilities at present. ‍♂️

Comment: That's clear now. The fact that we can't abstract it, makes it slightly inconvenient for my particular use case. But that answers the question with my simplified example. You can write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, TypeScript doesn't currently have the ability to express the type transformation you want, let alone carry it out.  At a minimum, we would need "generic generics" or "higher order generics" or "type constructor parameters" or "higher kinded types", as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).  TypeScript lets you write *specific* type functions, but we cannot write a *generic* one.

That is, imagine there were some magical type-like thing called `TypeFunc` and for every `F extends TypeFunc` then `F` is itself a generic type that takes a type parameter, so I could write `F<T>` without a compiler error.  Then maybe we could write

```
// Don't do this, it's not valid TypeScript:
type Foo<F extends TypeFunc> = {x: F<string>}
type G = Foo<Array> // type G = {x: Array<string>}
type H = Foo<Promise> // type H = {x: Promise<string>}
```

You recognize `Array` and `Promise` as specific type functions, but `F` is a *generic* one and it lets us defer applying type parameters to `Array` and `Promise`.

And then we could *maybe*, *possibly* define your `wrapper()` function like this:

```
// Don't try this, it's not valid TypeScript:
type Input<T extends Record<keyof T, TypeFunc>> = 
  { [K in keyof T]: { foo: <A>(...args: any) => T[K]<A> }};
type Output<T extends Record<keyof T, TypeFunc>, K extends keyof T, A> = 
  T[K]<A>;

declare const f: <T extends Record<keyof T, TypeFunc>>(
  t: Input<T>) => <K extends keyof T, A>() => Output<T, K, A>;
const wrapper = f(dict);
```

Because then we could potentially represent `dict`'s type as `Input<T>` for some type `T` whose properties are all `TypeFunc`s, and `wrapper()`'s output would be of type `Ouptut<T, K, A>` which is what you get when you take `T[K]`, a `TypeFunc`, and pass it `A` as a type argument.

But we don't have these higher kinded types in TypeScript, so we can't do this.

---

Your approach using [instantiation expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) is interesting, but, as you noticed, does not accomplish this.  Inside the implementation of `wrapper()`, the type of `fn` is a generic [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) type, but as soon as you call it you get the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all possible output types.  This is a TypeScript limitation as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47240](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47240).  And writing `fn<A>` apparently only gives you access to what would happen if you called `fn`, so by instantiating it with a type parameter you lose the indexed access.

It's a shame, because instantiation expressions do seem like they should give us some ability to express higher kinded types.  But they don't.

---

So, what are our options?

The closest I can get is to use instantiation expressions manually for each key of `dict` to build up a specific type function that behaves how you want, and then have the compiler verify that `dict` actually conforms to this type function so that you'd at least get warned if `dict` diverges from this.  Observe:

```
type DictMap<A> = {
  one: ReturnType<typeof dict.one.foo<A>>,
  two: ReturnType<typeof dict.two.foo<A>>,
  three: ReturnType<typeof dict.three.foo<A>>,
};

const wrapper = <K extends keyof Dict, A>() => {    
  const dictSentinel: { [P in keyof Dict]: { foo(a: A): DictMap<A>[P] } } = dict;
  // sentinel should let you know if something wrong has happened

  return null! as DictMap<A>[K];
}
```

The type `DictMap<A>[K]` type accurately represents what you get when you call `dict[k]<A>` when `k` is of type `K`, so you can just return `DictMap<A>[K]` from `wrapper()`:

```
const x = wrapper<'two', 7>();
// const x: readonly [7, 7]
```

And if someone changes `dict` (adds a new property or something) then you'll get errors somewhere inside `wrapper`, either in the type `DictMap<A>[P]` or in the assignment of `dictSentinel`.

No, it's not pretty.  I can't come up with anything better unless you have further advance knowledge of some pattern in the type of `dict`.  And the ideal solution is probably forever unattainable until and unless we get some higher kinded types in TypeScript.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-maxvpyzMXswP1QLsxmYZhg4MswXT-YqlPhfChMRDIDg4dqtFpkyrIACyLGK7ouKkIJEF8TA8rpb2lO6gJsIJtCZgY2h4egMMM7FEJ8aBfBo3xNACv1MRhf38QI72Ax9FjAxZXyqKCAgIAgYLCZU-28JcVwvdcvn7dZB1DNMKiqecmAnIwVCXN8+h2KAHgIQt9XELEYA1GiTygPUMANagIksDgSCE89L0YXiZFUbIvjfPM8GBGAiTADiwC4zS-BAIRCzgGBC0EGApSETUwBAXR+IaCB8UEPwHkeZdcSeGA-Fcby1x2Ag4BaWwHxgMAjMLABCNJaLPC8zBdKQ8yZJcNi+Ei-L4GghgAoYnAAdnHPMNJSkgBBYOBwELQoJDy-KpBwIA)